# Android Studio Volley Local Connection Failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I am trying to make a connection on my local wamp server with my mobile application to login Volley Library. The code is working fine when I upload my PHP files on a remote server (my domain hosting) but when I use the files on my localhost its not working its executing the onErrorResponse function.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.43.188/zupco_web/android/",
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Response is: "+ response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

I have tested the url in both mobile and PC browers its working. I am also connected to the same network (WiFi).

So how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Try setting: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` application tag.

Comment: Wow, thanks it worked.